# How to convert text to date format in google sheet?

Tags: date, google-sheets, text, format, date-format

In my google sheet I have a column with dates but its in a text format. here an example what I have:

```
Oct 01, 2021
Dec 25, 2020
...
...
```

I want to convert it to a date format

```
01/10/2021
25/12/2020
....
```

I need to find the number of days from the dates in this column, by using "date in column" - now(). This does not work with the format "Oct 01, 2021" since its a text, and I am getting an error from Googlesheet.
Thanks in advance
IS

Comment: share a copy of your sheet

Comment: Can you share a copy of the script? Does it have to be on 1 cell or do you have like one cell for the date formatted and one cell for the difference between the date and today?

Comment: here is the link: -  https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1bIDVNr3WJTgBKJMPmqZrI4a4SBvqrhDh0XpLgizGxyo/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Your sheet is not shared for us to access.  See here for guidelines.  https://support.google.com/docs/thread/3808684?hl=en

Comment: sorry. now should be ok

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this formula in F2:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(DATEDIF(
      DATE(
        RIGHT(E2:E,4),
        MATCH(LEFT(E2:E,3),{"Jan";"Feb";"Mar";"Apr";"May";"Jun";"Jul";"Aug";"Sep";"Oct";"Nov";"Dec"},0),
        MID(E2:E,5,2)), 
      NOW(), "D")))
```

### Update

Revised the formula, which goes in F1 and fills the column, to:

```
={"Days Left";ARRAYFORMULA(
  IFERROR(-1 * DATEDIF( DATE( RIGHT(E2:E,4), MATCH(LEFT(E2:E,3),{"Jan";"Feb";"Mar";"Apr";"May";"Jun";"Jul";"Aug";"Sep";"Oct";"Nov";"Dec"},0), MID(E2:E,5,2)), NOW(), "D"),
    IFERROR(DATEDIF( NOW(),DATE( RIGHT(E2:E,4), MATCH(LEFT(E2:E,3),{"Jan";"Feb";"Mar";"Apr";"May";"Jun";"Jul";"Aug";"Sep";"Oct";"Nov";"Dec"},0), MID(E2:E,5,2)),  "D"))))}
```

which reverses the date difference values.  It also handles date differences for dates either in the future, or in the past.

[image]

Comment: Note that you could "move" this formula up into the header row, into F1, by changing it to:  ={"Days Left";ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(DATEDIF(
      DATE(
        RIGHT(E2:E,4),
        MATCH(LEFT(E2:E,3),{"Jan";"Feb";"Mar";"Apr";"May";"Jun";"Jul";"Aug";"Sep";"Oct";"Nov";"Dec"},0),
        MID(E2:E,5,2)), 
      NOW(), "D")))}

Comment: I am getting errors. Please take a look at the sheet and see what I did, and the errors I got. In cells F1, F2, and F3

Comment: Delete everything in F2 and below.  The formula in F1 will fill the whole of column F.  If you read the error message in F1, it tells you it can't work, because of date in cell F2.  that is your clue that the formula, an "arrayformula" in this case, needs to fill more than one cell.

Comment: TSN, F8, has a date in the future, so the formula gives an error, but sets it to blank.  The formula can be updated to handle this, but what value would you want shown in F8?

Comment: Understood. Great! You hit it! Only one thing here, I want to calculate how many days were left before I hit the Ex-div date, which means i have to substract the Ex0dic day from today. So, in TSN I will get 77 and in others I will get a minus (-). Look at the right side column L where I calculated it. Could you please fix that for me? Big Thanks!!!

Comment: Try this:  ={"Days Left";ARRAYFORMULA(
  IFERROR(-1 * DATEDIF( DATE( RIGHT(E2:E,4), MATCH(LEFT(E2:E,3),{"Jan";"Feb";"Mar";"Apr";"May";"Jun";"Jul";"Aug";"Sep";"Oct";"Nov";"Dec"},0), MID(E2:E,5,2)), NOW(), "D"),
    IFERROR(DATEDIF( NOW(),DATE( RIGHT(E2:E,4), MATCH(LEFT(E2:E,3),{"Jan";"Feb";"Mar";"Apr";"May";"Jun";"Jul";"Aug";"Sep";"Oct";"Nov";"Dec"},0), MID(E2:E,5,2)),  "D"))))}  in F2.  If it doesn't work, the easiest way for me to help is if you share your sheet so anyone can EDIT, not just view.

Comment: You hit it! Great work. Thank you. I need to grant you your score. Any idea how I do it?

Comment: If you feel this is the best answer to your question, click the checkmark to the left of my answer.  You can also "upvote" it, using the up arrow.  You also get points yourself for doing this, since it helps other people find good answers.  Thanks, and glad to have helped!

Comment: Yes, you helped a lot. I checked it. Hope you got your score. Thx again!

Answer (score 1):

Use the `DATEVALUE()` function on a date string, then use `DATEDIF()` to find the difference between two dates.

`=DATEDIF(DATEVALUE("Oct 01, 2020"), DATEVALUE("Dec 25, 2020"), "D")`

UPDATE: To find the date between today and a date string in another cell use this example:

`=DATEDIF(DATEVALUE(A2), NOW(), "D")`

If cell A2 contains string `Oct 01, 2020`, it will return `70` for today 2020-12-10

Comment: I need to calculate the numbers of days from Today to the date in text.That is how many days left from Today to "Oct 01, 2021", and the same for other text days such as "Dec 25, 2020". I hope I am clear clear. Thanks!

Comment: No, your original description was confusing, let me revise the text

Comment: Ok, I added an UPDATE

Comment: I am getting an error using =DATEDIF(DATEVALUE(A2), NOW(), "D")

Comment: I can send you a snapshot of the error I got. Just dont know how to upload a file....sorry

Comment: Error
Function MINUS parameter 1 expects number values. But 'Feb 26, 2021' is a text and cannot be coerced to a number.

Comment: Here is the link to the entire sheet - https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1bIDVNr3WJTgBKJMPmqZrI4a4SBvqrhDh0XpLgizGxyo/edit?usp=sharing